# How to delete files for date with script

Tags: powershell

I have a script for deleting files, folders and subfolders, but I will want delete for date, 1 days ago for example, I add in my script these parameters `"/D -1 or /D +01 or D/ +1"` but isn't run.

Below is my script:

```
del /q "C:\Users\gabrielp3081_00\Documents\new\*"
FOR /D +01 %%p IN ("C:\Users\gabrielp3081_00\Documents\new\*") DO rmdir "%%p" /s /q 
exit
```

Comment: Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $Path | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Date).Add(-1)} | Remove-Item #-Recurse add this to remvoe subfolders and files

Comment: Why did you tag this `PowerShell` ??

Comment: Because, this script is executed for ".bat".

Answer (score 1):

To delete the files that were modified 1 day ago use this:

```
& "C:\Windows\System32\forfiles.exe" /p "FilePath" /s /m *.* /d -1 /c "cmd /c del @path"
```

Comment: So, i do this changes, but isn`t working, you can see my erros? my scritp .bat is bellow.

del /q "C:\Users\gabrielp3081_00\Documents\new\*"
FOR /D %%p IN ("C:\Users\gabrielp3081_00\Documents\new\*") /p "C:\Users\gabrielp3081_00\Documents\new\*" /s /m *.* /d -1 /c "cmd /c del @path"
exit